# Xamarin TimePicker propertychanged event fired on load

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, timepicker, propertychanged

I am developing a Xamarin app for android using Xamarin forms to create my layout. I have come across an issue with my time picker firing on load of my view cell.

What I am doing is creating a list view and then setting the item template to my custom view cell template. In my view cell template I am creating a TimePicker and binding a PropertyChanged event to it. I am also setting the TimePicker.Time property with information retrieved from the database. What seems to happen at this point is that my PropertyChanged event is fired for each item that will be displayed in the list view. This leads to multiple database calls that are not needed.

Is there a way to stop the PropertyChanged event being called until a property has actually been changed?

My code is below.

```
public class MyCell : ViewCell
{
private readonly TimePicker _myTimePicker;
public MyCell()
{
   _myTimePicker = new TimePicker()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
        };

        _myTimePicker.SetBinding(TimePicker.TimeProperty, "StartTime");
        _myTimePicker.PropertyChanged += MyTimePicker_PropertyChanged;

        var viewLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Padding = new Thickness(20),
            Children = { _myTimePicker }
        };
        View = viewLayout;
}

private void MyTimePicker_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName && _myTimePicker.Time != TimeSpan.MinValue)
        {
            var dataAccess = new DataAccessLayer();
            dataAccess.Update(myTimePicker.Time);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the propertychanged event is fired multiple times and how to stop it firing until I actually pick a time. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code for the form to display the list view. All my xaml is defined in code. 'MyCell' uses the values returned from '_dataAccess.GetTimes()'.

```
public class TimeDetails : ContentPage
{
    private ListView _listView;
    private readonly DataAccessLayer _dataAccess = new DataAccessLayer();

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        _listView = new ListView
        {
            RowHeight = 80,
            SeparatorColor = Color.Blue,
            SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.Default
        };

        _listView.ItemsSource = _dataAccess.GetTimes();
        _listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyCell));
        _listView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = { _listView }
        };
    }
}
```

The return type of _dataAcess.GetTimes() is List of TaskTime. The TaskTime model is shown below.

```
public class TaskTime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I assume this code you posted is in your page? Can you also post your xaml and code how you bind to listview? Specifically where you assign your ItemSource and ItemBindingTemplate. It is not clear if you do it in xaml or somewhere in code. Then I can try to reproduce

Comment: The code I originally posted is in my custom cell which is used in my list view item template. I have made edits to the original question with the information you requested. Thanks.

Comment: Is MyCell derived from something? I see View = viewLayout; but there is no view in MyCell. Also what _dataAccess.GetTimes(); returns? There is no bindings defined in listView. Can you put the whole source code somewhere so I can help you faster?

Comment: Updates are above with the questions asked. I'm not sure where I can put the code for you to have a look at.

Comment: Dropbox or github

Comment: I recreated the project. see an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyCell : ViewCell
{
    private readonly TimePicker _myTimePicker;
    public MyCell()
    {
        _myTimePicker = new TimePicker()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
        };

        _myTimePicker.SetBinding(TimePicker.TimeProperty, "StartTime");
        _myTimePicker.PropertyChanged += MyTimePicker_PropertyChanged;
        _myTimePicker.Focused += _myTimePicker_Focused;

        var viewLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Padding = new Thickness(20),
            Children = { _myTimePicker }
        };
        View = viewLayout;
    }

    bool myTimePickerSelected;
    private void _myTimePicker_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        myTimePickerSelected = true;
    }

    private void MyTimePicker_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.PropertyName == TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName && myTimePickerSelected)
        {
            //var dataAccess = new DataAccessLayer();
            //dataAccess.Update(myTimePicker.Time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does make sense. Do you know of any way this can be stopped?

Comment: yes. Don't subscribe for Property change but then you will not know when time is selected

Comment: I do need to know when time is selected as will need to update the database with the selected time. I'll have a play with other things to see if I can get around it.

Comment: I've managed to fix the issue, you can tell me if it's a good solution before I post it as the answer. I've created a new TimePicker and set the value of "StartTime" to it (the same as I do with _myTimePicker). Then added to the if statement and compare the values of my two TimePickers. When I modify _myTimePicker then the values are different and so the update code in property changed event runs. In there I now also set the new TimePicker to the new value of _myTimePicker. How does that sound?

Comment: if you want you can play with Unfocused event with PropertyChanged event subscribing and unsubscribing.

Comment: It is up to you. I personally don't see any problems with getting all properties.

Comment: when do you check if time is different between pickers?

Comment: It's an added clause to the existing if statement. 'if (e.PropertyName == TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName && _myTimePicker.Time != _newTimePicker.Time)'

Comment: Adding another timepicker is overhead. It is enough to have just timespan. I have updated my answer.

Comment: actually you don't even need pickerTime. In theory you can use boolean firstTime to avoid database update the first time the cell loaded. After that time change property will be called only if time was changed. But if you want to be ABSOLUTELY sure you can use             if (e.PropertyName == TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName && pickerTime != TimeSpan.MinValue && pickerTime != _myTimePicker.Time) but it is overkill

Comment: I slightly amended your answer to use a boolean like you suggested in your last comment, that seemed like the better solution. I have tested and it works well for me. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Usman26's edit to use a boolean instead of comparing the actual change, I recommend against. That relies on PropertyChanged event firing once when the cell is loaded. Suppose there is a platform where that doesn't happen? In that case, the boolean would suppress a legitimate change. The original logic, that compares the actual value, is the safe approach.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution using focused & unfocused event is :

```
public class CustomTimePicker : TimePicker
{
    public event EventHandler TimeChanged;

    private TimeSpan StartValue { get; set; }

    public CustomTimePicker ()
    {
        this.Focused += OnFoused;
        this.Unfocused += OnUnfocused;
    }

    private void OnFoused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        StartValue = this.Time;
    }

    private void OnUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (StartValue != this.Time)
        {
            TimeChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i have seen is that `OnAppearing()` is finished when all initialization is done. Maybe you could introduce a boolean variable that you then use in `PropertyChanged()` method. It is a trick because you have to do it from `ContentPage`, and pass a value to your control when initialization is finished.
I just saw, ther is `OnAppearing()` method in CellView, this way everything stays in your control class.